# Last axis label is missing

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, axis

I have the following PSTricks code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp}
    \begin{pspicture}(-176,-176)(176,176)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[showorigin=true,xAxis=true,Dy=10,dy=25.6,Dx=32,Ox=-128](-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{0pt}[0](-160,0){{\large\itshape{L}}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It works fine. Except, the 100 label on the y-axis is missing. How do I get it back? Thanks.

[edit]

As a workaround, I tried multiplying all the dimensions by 10 to avoid the decimal point. But now the output image dimensions and text size are too small.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=10pt,arrowsize=80pt,unit=1bp}
    \begin{pspicture}(-1760,-1760)(1760,1760)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=20pt}
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=20pt,showorigin=true,xAxis=true,Dy=10,dy=256,Dx=320,Ox=-1280,ticksize=-40pt 40pt](-1280,-1280)(-1280,-1280)(1280,1280)
    \uput{0pt}[0](-1600,0){{\large\itshape{L}}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you slightly increase the maximum value of the y coordinate in `\psaxes`, it's OK. Maybe this comes from a rounding error.

```
\psaxes[showorigin=true,xAxis=true,Dy=10,dy=25.6,Dx=32,Ox=-128](-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128.01)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `dy=25.599`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=1pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(-176,-176)(176,176)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[Dy=10,dy=25.599,Dx=32,dx=32,Ox=-128](-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{0pt}[0](-160,0){{\large\itshape{L}}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```